# Android Basic Activity & ListView - Progress Bar Not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I have an Android activity as basic activity which have below layout -

[image: Layout]

And below is the xml for the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_read_contacts"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="au.com.savedme.ReadContacts">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/readContactLv" />

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/readContactPb"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_cloud_upload_white_24dp"
    android:id="@+id/readContactFab"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

I am starting this activity from another activity. My goal is to make progress bar visible in onCreate method and then loading the listview, once the list view is populated with items I want to make the progress bar invisible.

My questions are

- if I start populating the list view the progress bar is not visible at all no matter what I try.
- if I skip populating the list view the progress bar is visible clearly.
- if I am populating the list view there is a significant delay in navigation from previous activity and the screen just freezes and gets black(And Blank) and once the list is populated it comes back, which doesn't give any visual clue to user that something happening (not desired).

What should I do to prevent this, below is my onCreate method -

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_contacts);

    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.readContactPb);
    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Variable initialisations
    contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    contactListTosave = new ArrayList<>();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mContactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.readContactLv);
    mContactListView.setOnItemClickListener(onClickListener);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.readContactFab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for (Contact contactToSave:contactListTosave){
                mDatabase.child("contacts").child(userId).child(contactToSave.getFirstName()).setValue(contactToSave);
            }
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ContactList.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new ContactArrayAdapter(ReadContacts.this, 0, contactList);
        mContactListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    checkPermissionToReadContact();
}
```

And below is the code for my listAdapter -

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
* Created by AppsWise on 15/10/16.
*/

public class ContactArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Contact> contactsProperties;
    private String TAG = "ContactArrayAdapter";

//constructor, call on creation
public ContactArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Contact> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.contactsProperties = objects;
}

// Called when rendering the view
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // get properties we are displaying
    Contact contact = contactsProperties.get(position);

    //Get inflater and inflate the XML layout for each item
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(MainActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, null);
    TextView nameText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    TextView contactName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
    TextView number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phoneText);

    String completeName = "";
    if(contact.getFirstName()!=null){
        completeName = contact.getFirstName();
    }
    if(contact.getLastName()!=null){
        completeName += "  "+contact.getLastName();
    }
    if (completeName!=null && completeName.trim().length()>0) {
        if (nameText!=null) {
            nameText.setText(completeName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase());
        }
        contactName.setText(completeName);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && contact.getIsUploaded() ){
            nameText.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        }
    }
    number.setText(contact.getPhone());
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: can show your xml file

Comment: create a interface in your adapter class and when the adapter work is completed , use this interface to pass the completed state to activity.then u can stop the progress in that callback

Comment: @Ak9637 Sorry I didn't get it, can you please explain a bit more about creating an interface in adapter class?

Comment: can u post the code of the list adapter

Comment: Instead of setting your `ProgressBar` in the layout Create one custom Dialog and set it there. while you are fetching data show the `Dialog` and when the result is come `Dismiss` the `Dialog`.

Comment: In what thread loading is hapenning, can you show code of fetching results?

Answer (score 1):

While you are fetching the data to the ListView, keep your ListView `VISIBILITY` as `GONE`. Once your ListView is loaded, set the ProgressBar `VISIBILITY` as `INVISIBLE`

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code it will work
The problem is one view is overlapped on another (i.e listview on progress)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_contacts);

mContactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.readContactLv);
mContactListView.setOnItemClickListener(onClickListener);
mContactListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.readContactPb);
pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// Variable initialisations
contactList = new ArrayList<>();
contactListTosave = new ArrayList<>();
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.readContactFab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        for (Contact contactToSave:contactListTosave){
            mDatabase.child("contacts").child(userId).child(contactToSave.getFirstName()).setValue(contactToSave);
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ContactList.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

if (mAdapter == null) {
    mAdapter = new ContactArrayAdapter(ReadContacts.this, 0, contactList);
    mContactListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //Disabling progress here
    mContactListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
checkPermissionToReadContact();
}
```

Comment: is your list items are displaying ?

Comment: Yes once the result is fetched all list items are visible.

Comment: what about the progress bar?

Comment: In above code if I comment the `checkPermissionToReadContact()` method the progress bar is visible and the list doesn't get populated but when I un-comment it the list gets populated but above mentioned problems happens.

Comment: can you post code for checkPermissionToReadContact()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129432/discussion-between-jefriiyer-s-and-apps-wise).